# Is it possible to get enemy AI to fly helicopters in far cry 5s arcade editor?

Tags: far-cry-5

I thought having enemy helicopters in my levels would be pretty awesome but I’ve no clue how to accomplish this

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, put an enemy near a helicopter, then put a control zone far away from the enemy and link the enemy to it, he will get on the chopper